# SQL: How to join the two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. I need to join them, but I have a doubt since these two tables do not have a common column name.

**people**

| id | name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | Days | F |
| 145 | Hawbaker | M |
| 155 | Hansel | F |
| 202 | Blackston | M |
| 227 | Criss | F |
| 278 | Keffer | M |
| 305 | Canty | M |
| 329 | Mozingo | F |
| 425 | Nolf | M |
| 534 | Waugh | F |
| 586 | Tong | M |
| 618 | Dimartino | F |
| 747 | Beane | M |
| 878 | Chatmon | F |
| 904 | Hansard | F |

**relations**

| c_id | p_id |
| --- | --- |
| 145 | 202 |
| 145 | 107 |
| 278 | 305 |
| 278 | 155 |
| 329 | 425 |
| 329 | 227 |
| 534 | 586 |
| 534 | 878 |
| 618 | 747 |
| 618 | 904 |

Desired output:

| child | father | mother |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dimartino | Beane | Hansard |
| Hawbaker | Blackston | Days |
| Keffer | Canty | Hansel |
| Mozingo | Nolf | Criss |
| Waugh | Tong | Chatmon |

My approach:

```
select distinct 
    people.name as child, 
    people.name as father, people.name as mother
from
    relations 
inner join 
    people on relaions.c_id = people.id
```

This is the output of this query:

| child | father | mother |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dimartino | Dimartino | Dimartino |
| Hawbaker | Hawbaker | Hawbaker |
| Keffer | Keffer | Keffer |
| Mozingo | Mozingo | Mozingo |
| Waugh | Waugh | Waugh |

How to get the desired output in order of the name of the child?

Comment: would it be easier to add to the "people" table, the "people_father_id" and "people_mother_id"  ?? (unless you can have multiple fathers and/or mothers) ---   |  id  |  name   |  gender  |  people_father_id   |  people_mother_id -- then you can join the same tables 2 times with different alias (one for father, one for mother)

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should always tag SQL requests with the DBMS in question, because answers may heavily depend on that.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, my dbms is ms sql. Thanks a lot for your responses!

Comment: MS SQL? You mean Microsoft SQL Server I suppose? Or do you mean Microsoft Access?

Comment: Yes, it is Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Okay, I've adapted my answer, for SQL Server doesn't support the standard SQL `USING` clause. I've also tagged your request with `sql-server`.

Comment: What makes, for example, the father of `Dimartino` `Beane` given that `Beane`'s gender is `F`?

Comment: SQL joins on common values, not on common column names.

Comment: @Charlieface, agreed. This is a question from a assignment problem.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', thanks for pointing my mistake out.

Comment: So what result do you want? Explain the Desired output, or change it, or change the source data, otherwise something is wrong

Comment: I changed the source data, @Charlieface. Output will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Join the people table twice, once for the parent, once for the child. Then group by child and use conditional aggregation to get father and mother.

```
select
  c.name as child,
  max(case when p.gender = 'M' then p.name end) as father,
  max(case when p.gender = 'F' then p.name end) as mother
from relations r
join people p on p.id = r.p_id
join people c on c.id = r.c_id
group by c.id, c.name
order by c.name;
```

And just to show that this is also possible of course without aggregation (and to show an approach that may come easier to mind when you are a beginner):

```
with fathers as
(
  select p.name, r.c_id
  from relations r
  join people p on p.id = r.p_id
  where p.gender = 'M'
)
, mothers as
(
  select p.name, r.c_id
  from relations r
  join people p on p.id = r.p_id
  where p.gender = 'F'
)
, children as
(
  select c.name, c.id as c_id
  from people c
  where c.id in (select r.c_id from relations r)
)
select
  children.name as child,
  fathers.name as father,
  mothers.name as mother
from children
left join mothers on mothers.c_id = children.c_id
left join fathers on fathers.c_id = children.c_id
order by children.name;
```

I am using outer joins here for the case that a child's mother or father is unknown (i.e. not in the relation table).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this code did not work.

Comment: "It did not work" tells me nothing. Which of the two queries did not work? What did not work? Did you get a syntax error, a runtime error, too many rows, too few rows, ...? Elaborate.

Comment: As to the first query, I've added `c.name`to the group by clause. According to the SQL standard, this should not be necessary, but it seems SQL Server fails to detect the functional dependency to `c.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested joins should work neatly. No CTEs or grouping necessary.

- Left join `relations`...
- ... and within that, inner join `people` who have gender `F`
- Repeat again for gender `M`
- Exclude any who already have children

```sql
select
  c.name as child,
  father.name as father,
  mother.name as mother
from people c
left join relations rm
    join people mother on mother.id = rm.p_id and mother.gender = 'F'
  on rm.c_id = c.id
left join relations rf
    join people father on father.id = rf.p_id and father.gender = 'M'
  on rf.c_id = c.id
where c.id not in (
  select r.p_id
  from relations r
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e02a8e80d0c292e40bf1dc8eb55bf62f)